# which form of property declaration is more appropriate?

Tags: c#, properties

It's been a while this simple question is disturbing me , I've seen two form of declaring properties , and I was wondering what's the different and Is there any reason that makes me prefer one to another ?

1st Form :

```
public int Age { get; set; }
```

2nd Form :

```
private int _Age;
public int Age
{
    get { return _Age; }
    set { _Age = value; }
}
```

I've always used the second form and also I've seen this [MSDN Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) just talks about the 2nd form , so I'm a little confused here , which one is preferred ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first form is fairly "new". So you will find a lot of "old" code that contains the second form.

Today, using modern versions of C#, the only reason to use the second form is to hook up more logic inside the getter or setter.

For instance:

```
private int myPropertyValue;

public int MyProperty
{
    get 
    {
        return myPropertyValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value >= 0 && value <= 100)
        {
            myPropertyValue = value;
        }
        else
        {
            // throw exception here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another reason to use the explicit field is so for a read only property you can make the backing field read only too - nice for immutable classes

Answer (score 1):

The first one is fine when you aren't doing any extra processing or access control on the property. It's just a quicker way of doing it, introduced in C# 3.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's really a matter of preference.  The first format is just syntactical sugar, where you have the compiler generating the second format for you.  If I’m not doing any manipulation or evaluation, I prefer to go with the first form as it’s shorter and tidier.  But as others have pointed out, if you are doing pre C# 3, then you have no choice but to do the second form

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the first form only if I have a dumb class that does nothing with the field itself i.e. it is just storing a value.

I would therefore, in most situations, use the second form. This allows you to add validation logic to the getter/setter for external (to the class) consumers, but when accessing the field from methods internal to the class, I concider it to be more of a closed ecosystem where so much validation is often just a waste of processor cycles.